# An equivalent but differentiable argmax expression in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a one-hot representation for the maximum value in a tensor.

For example, consider a tensor `2 x 3`:

```
[ [1, 5, 2],
  [0, 3, 7] ]
```

The *one-hot-argmax* representation I am aiming for looks like this:

```
[ [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1] ]
```

I can do it as follows, where `my_tensor` is a `N x 3` tensor:

```
position = tf.argmax(my_tensor, axis=1).      # Shape (N x )
one_hot_pos = tf.one_hot(position, depth=3)   # Shape (N x 3)
```

But this part of the code need be differentiable since I'm training over it.
My workaround was as follows, where `EPSILON = 1e-3` is a small constant:

```
max_value = tf.reduce_max(my_tensor, axis=1, keepdims=True)
clip_min = max_value - EPSILON
one_hot_pos = (tf.clip_by_value(my_tensor, clip_min, max_value) - clip_min) / (max_value - clip_min)
```

The workaround works most of the time, but - as expected - it has some issues:

- Sensible to `EPSILON`: if it is too small, a division by zero might happen
- Can't solve ties: `argmax` only chooses one even in a tie situation

Do you know any better way of simulating the `argmax` followed by `one_hot` situation, while fixing the two mentioned issues, but using only differentiable Tensorflow functions?

Comment: Have you tried using `softmax(x)` instead of `one_hot(argmax(x))`?

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately, ``softmax`` would not output the `0` or `1` behaviour I am looking for. To make this clear, I've added an example to my question.

Comment: I understand that softmax would not output 0 and 1 but softmax would output something that is differentiable. Softmax([0, 3, 7]) will give [8.95e-4, 0.018, 0.98] which is very close to [0, 0, 1]. Plus this would solve the tie issue as well by assigning same values to both. If you need the output to have 0 and 1 only, then I am not sure what would be a good approach.

Comment: That is a good idea, Lakshay, I will try it. But I do need the `0`s and `1`s. This *mask* is used to block (or allow) some computation through. This works like a dropout (sort of), though only one can be chosen here.

Comment: Sounds to me like max-pooling of some sort. Am I correct?

Comment: And since you are using this as some kind of dropout, the flow of gradient will be negligible, which should be good enough. However, there is no substitute for experimentation ;)

Comment: It does indeed. I didn't see this perspective before. I think I wouldn't be able to simply apply a ``MaxPool`` though because the output *mask* is sliced right next. That is, the position of the `0`'s and `1`'s play a part in this model.

Comment: What did you end up doing? This is exactly what I'm trying to do, and funnily enough my current solution is exactly what you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Do some maximum, tile and multiplication operations. Like:

```
a = tf.Variable([ [1, 5, 2], [0, 3, 7] ]) # your tensor

m = tf.reduce_max(a, axis=1) #  [5,7]
m = tf.expand_dims(m, -1)    # [[5],[7]]
m = tf.tile(m, [1,3])        # [[5,5,5],[7,7,7]]

y = tf.cast(tf.equal(a,m), tf.float32)) # [[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

This is a tricky multiplication operation that is differentiable.